# Creating user account without admin or control panel

Tags: user-accounts, uac, non-admin

Simply put I need to create a basic user account on the computer without using control panel and without running any programs such as cmd with admin.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Also I can view but cannot edit the registry

Comment: Can't be done AFAIK. Why can't you use the Control Panel or CMD and why can't you do it as an administrator?

Comment: He obviously is on a limited account himself and he needs another account that doesn't have administrative privileges, probably to test something or for a friend, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Creating a user account is an administrative task and thus requires administrative privileges.

Comment: Is there any way I can enable a guest account?

Comment: No. All actions regarding users are required to have administrative privileges. The exception to this rule is basic changes to your own account, such as changing your name or password. Ask whoever has access to the administrator account to make you a 2nd user.